# Eclipse testing with multiple projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, I am trying to set-up a JUnit test suite with multiple projects. I have my main project, which I'll call App, that needs to be tested. Originally, I also had a second project named AndroidTestProject with several packages in order to run JUnit tests on the app. This project had several src packages:

```
test.app.perf
test.app.sanity
test.app.base
test.app.fact
test.app.dev
test.app.util
```

What I want to do in order to make things cleaner is create a third project called framework for the base packages. My hierarchy would then be:

```
App
 various src packages

Framework
 test.app.base
 test.app.fact
 test.app.dev
 test.app.util

TestProject
 test.app.perf
 test.app.sanity
```

However, when I went through with this everything is fine except that I get a RunTime exception when trying to run tests in the sanity package. Eclipse cannot find any java classes in the sanity package even though they are present and what I am trying to run. Did I mess up a dependency somewhere?

For reference, I have Framework in TestProject's build path so I don't think it is that. But my JUnit tests ran fine when everything was in TestProject as opposed to divided between the two projects.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Exact exception:

```
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo{test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find test class. Class: test.app.sanity.Tests
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4058)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1219)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find test class. Class: test.app.sanity.Tests
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at  android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runFailed(AndroidTestRunner.java:233)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.loadTestClass(AndroidTestRunner.java:87)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:48)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:80)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at  android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:426)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:407)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:362)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4055)
07-08 15:33:28.309: E/AndroidRuntime(30276):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: What is the exact exception? Also, does Framework contain test code or is it part of your app?

Comment: If it compiles it shouldn't be a path problem. I agree with Monad, can we see the exception please.

Comment: Just added the exception to the page. Framework contains test code, it is not part of the app. It's mainly abstract classes and the utility methods which sanity and perf use to do things.

Comment: What are the Android package names of each project? And which test project are you running? Do you run Framework directly or do you run TestProject?

Comment: I'm running a JUnit test file in TestProject. TestProject has the code to run actual tests, Framework is primarily abstract.